# Cassandra PHP client - Invalid or unsupported protocol version

Tags: php, cassandra

I am trying Cassandra (3.0.9) nosql database on windows local machine with language php.

I use this php client: https://github.com/evseevnn/php-cassandra-binary

My code:

```
$nodes = ['127.0.0.1:9042'];
$database = new \evseevnn\Cassandra\Database($nodes, 'people');
$database->connect();
```

Exception error:

```
evseevnn\Cassandra\Exception\ConnectionException: Protocol error: Invalid or unsupported protocol version (1); the lowest supported version is 3 and the greatest is 4
```

Where do I set protocol version?

**UPDATE**

This repository deprecated and not maintained anymore.
Use https://github.com/duoshuo/php-cassandra